# Failed to mount early API filesystems. Systemd[1]:Freezing Execution

Tags: boot, 20.04, mount, freeze

This is what I see when I try to boot:

https://ibb.co/GtkDSNQ

The final error reads:

```
Failed to mount early API filesystems.
Systemd[1]:Freezing Execution
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Way too fuzzy to read, at least for me. What is the error message?

Comment: Failed to mount early API filesystems. Systemd[1]:Freezing Execution

Comment: Are you running in a Docker?

Comment: Am not running a Docker